# How can I create MLM table design

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm trying to create a table for MLM (multi-level marketing) but I'm having a problem on creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `mlmpair_tbl` (
    `parentid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `left` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `right` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `pairamount` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I don't know if I'm on the right track. The requirement is quite simple if the member has left and right nodes then he will be given some points and also his parents node will be given some points.

I hope someone can advice me or give me some pointers.

**Added some data:**

```
parentid          left      right        amount
11                 12                    0.00
12                 13         14         1000.00
13                 15         16         1000.00
```

the second row has left and right so his parentid 12 will be given some points example 1000.00,then 11 is the parentid of 12 so parentid 11 will be given also some pionts.
in the the third row parentid 13 has completed left and right nodes so he will be given points,then his parentsid are 12,11 will be given some points also 1000.00.

this is what i want to achieve.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your create statement is fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53bdd.

Comment: but I am confuse on how to update the amount if there is row completed left and right to all his parentsid.

Comment: most likely this is some kind of a tree node parent children with unlimited depth structure. man, this is going to be a pain trying to match pairing nodes, unless you find an algorithm for that.

Comment: @Ghost, have you gone this kind project before ?or do you have some experience on your past projects?I hope your can help me

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you are aiming to do here?   Could you perhaps provide a few rows of what you expect this data to look like?  And a clearer idea of what the question is?  Thanks!

Comment: @ashTon im aware of a multi level marketing stuff, like pairing, and cross line, and some stuff since i have attended some BOM of those companies, but i haven't been involved in making a system such as this, so no, im sorry i can't help you with it, maybe you could research more a bit about this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to have a correct definition of 'amount' to deal with this. But, once you have the method how to calculate it, probably you realize that it is a better idea to calculate it with a procedure instead of storing its value in the table. However, it arises some performance issues, etc. so it depends on your purpose...